# Custom formats set in logging.basicConfig for StreamHandler

Tags: python-3.x, logging

I have two log handlers set up in my basic config. The `FileHandler` logs to a file and `StreamHandler` logs to stdout.

```
logging.basicConfig(
    format="%(asctime)s [%(threadName)-12.12s] [%(levelname)-5.5s]  %(message)s",
    level=logging.INFO,
    handlers=[
        logging.FileHandler("/my/log/file.log"),
        logging.StreamHandler(sys.stdout)
    ]
)
```

Currently, the above code works fine, however, I want my `StreamHandler` to output a different format, just the `%(message)`.

Is there a way to specify this in my `logging.basicConfig`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Predefine the `StreamHandler` and set your desired custom format before passing it to `basicConfig`:

```
handler_sh = logging.StreamHandler(sys.stdout)
handler_sh.setFormatter(logging.Formatter("%(message)s"))
```

You can now pass the created `handler` with an already set formatter to `basicConfig`:

```
logging.basicConfig(
    format="%(asctime)s [%(threadName)-12.12s] [%(levelname)-5.5s]  %(message)s",
    level=logging.INFO,
    handlers=[
        logging.FileHandler("/my/log/file.log"),
        handler_sh
    ]
)
```

Only the `FileHandler` takes the `format` passed in `basicConfig`:

> Any handlers which don’t already have a formatter set will be assigned
>   the default formatter created in this function.

Comment: Perfect, exactly what I was looking for. Thanks!